Inverse Probability of Weighting in Directed acyclic graph for a binary collider as a selection bias
For a confounder, like the following figure, it is commonly suggested that use of the Inverse Probability of Weighting can remove the path from confounder to exposure so that it removes the backdoor of confounding effect.

However, I find this principle seems not directly apply to a collider situation. In a binary collider as a selection bias, we only analyze data with observed ones, which causing a conditional on collider.

I was expected that use of the Inverse Probability of Weighting from exposure to collider, and no selection bias should exist; however, I am wroing. Use the weighted regression, the results remain same biased association between exposure and outcome in the weighted regression, as it did before IPW weight.

Only I model the collider with exposure and outcome, I can remove the selection bias in the weighted regression between exposure and outcome.
Can anyone tell why when my propensity score model of censoring = treatment only cannot solved the selection bias, and how to use dag to represent when my propensity score model of censoring = treatment.
I provide r code to demonstrate what I said:
library(tidyverse)

# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)
n=10000
# Generating the data
t <- tibble(
  x = rbinom(n, 1, 1/2),  # Bernoulli distribution for x
  y = rbinom(n, 1, 1/2),   # Bernoulli distribution for y
  c = rbinom(n, 1, plogis(2 * x - 3 * y))  # Logistic function for c
  )

# Correct results
summary(glm(y ~ x, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = t))

# Biased results
summary(glm(y ~ x, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = t, subset=c==0))

# Propensity score matching where c = x and only
psmodel=glm(c==0 ~ x, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = t)

#ps
t$ps <- predict(psmodel, newdata = t, type = "response")#data可以套到新的上面
#unstabilized weight
t$weight=ifelse(t$c==0, 1/(t$ps), 1/(1-t$ps))

# Biased results between x and y
summary(glm(y ~ x, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = t, subset=c==0, weights=weight))


# Propensity score matching where c = x and only
psmodel=glm(c==0 ~ x + y, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = t)

t$ps <- predict(psmodel, newdata = t, type = "response")#data可以套到新的上面
#unstabilized weight
t$weight=ifelse(t$c==0, 1/(t$ps), 1/(1-t$ps))

# correct results between x and y, but standard error is not corrected in currect analysis 
summary(glm(y ~ x, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = t, subset=c==0, weights=weight))

